# Linked list, why am I getting the Incompatible type and incomplete struct error

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

Let say I have 2 struct.

```
    typedef struct name{
    char*name;
    struct test *next;
    }name_t;

    typedef struct test {
    int grade;
    int studentNumber;
    struct test *next;
    }test_t;
```

so the marker have a pointer to the test how would I go create the link list?

I tried this

```
name_t *marker1 = malloc(sizeof(name_t));
// added name from another function
test_t *temp= malloc(sizeof(test_t));
// add the grade and student number from another function
if(marker1->next==NULL)
marker1->next=temp;
```

but it gives me the error

how would I go about fixing this? This is my first time coding linked list so any help would be appreciated

edit: also I made the following into a function

```
void test(name_t* marker1,int data)
{
        test_t *temp= malloc(sizeof(test_t));
        test_t *location=NULL;
        temp->grade=data;
        temp->next=NULL;
        location=marker1->next;
        if(location==NULL)
        {
        //  printf("%i \n",temp->grade);
            marker1->next=temp;
        }
        else
        {
            while(location!=NULL)
            {
                printf("%i \n",location->grade);
                printf("%p \n",location->next);
                location=location->next;
            }
            location=temp;
        }
}
```

it does not seem to go though the list for some reason. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`struct test *next;` refers to a `tag` name `test`.

```
typedef struct THIS_IS_WHERE_TAG_NAME_SHOULD_BE {
  ...
} test;
```

And you don't have such a tag name anywhere. Add it.

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in the second block of your program. You have written

```
if(marker1==NULL)
marker1->next=temp;
```

Previous to this you have written

```
name *marker1 = malloc(sizeof(name));
```

marker1 will be NULL only when malloc is not able to allocate any memory for you and returns NULL. When marker1 is NULL, you cannot access marker1->next which leads to a segmentation fault. Malloc  returns NULL when you ask for the amount of memory which crosses the limits and  the if statement you have written will not be true. But the statement inside the if block should be avoided. It is a wrong practice to code where you are trying to access the data when the pointer is NULL.

Comment: he has written: marker1->next == NULL and not marker1 == NULL.

Comment: The question was edited and then it was changed to marker1->next == NULL. It was marker1 == NULL before. Because I copied and pasted the code block in my reply.